# How do I remove an entire sentence that includes certain text?

Tags: php, regex

I have this so far:

```
preg_replace("([^\.\?\!]NNNNNNNNNN)[\.\?\!]","",$string);
```

and I also tried

```
preg_replace("([^\.\?\!]\N\N\N\N\N\N\N\N\N\N)[\.\?\!]","",$string);
```

But it's removing everything in $string.

The text I need to find (and remove the containing sentence) is: "NNNNNNNNNN"

Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
preg_replace("/(^|[.?!])[^.?!]*N{10}[^.?!]*[.?!]/g", "$1", $string);
```

I'll break it down, but I don't know if it will work.

- `(^|[.?!])` - the end of the previous sentence - captured
- `[^.?!]*` - possible multiple things that are not a end of sentence indicator
- `N{10}` - what you want to match
- `[^.?!]*` - possible multiple things that are not a end of sentence indicator
- `[.?!]` - the end of your sentence

Results in PHP:

> user@domain:~$ php -a
> Interactive shell
>
> php > $string = "This is a test. This is NNNNNNNNNN. This is still a test! Or is it?";
>
> php > print preg_replace("/(^|[.?!])[^.?!]*N{10}[^.?!]*[.?!]/", "$1", $string);
>
> This is a test. This is still a test! Or is it?

Comment: Well, that would work if I were only removing the string NNNNNNNNNN but I need to remove the entire sentence that has NNNNNNNNNN in it.

Comment: I misunderstood. I tried to edit my answer. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. When I try the regex in a tester, it finds the whole sentence, but when used in preg_replace, it empties the string. Hrmm...

Comment: Try `'(?:(?:^|[^.?!]*?)N{10}[^.?!]*?[.?!])'` instead and just replace with an empty string instead of a backreference. It's close enough to gpojd's answer that I won't bother posting another one. gpojd can update his if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. It's so weird. @gpojd original regex works here: http://www.regextester.com/ but I get errors here: http://www.functions-online.com/preg_replace.html

And this still empties the string: `preg_replace("(^|[.?!])[^.?!]*N{10}[^.?!]*[.?!]", '$1', $string);`

Comment: I updated it again with a transcript of my PHP session. I think it didn't work because I forgot to put the regex between slashes like `/regex/`.

Comment: @gpojd FYI... your pattern breaks on `This is a NNNNNNNNNN. This is a NNNNNNNNNN.`

Comment: Thanks again! Worked well with another `/` on the end, making it `preg_replace("/(^|[.?!])[^.?!]*N{10}[^.?!]*[.?!]/", "$1", $string);`